# Google Play : An error occurred while getting the status of your purchase

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I'm unable to buy apps from the Play Store.

This is the message I get when trying to buy the app from a desktop computer :

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: desktop error]

This is what I get when I try to purchase the app from my device (Nexus 5) :
It's in French, in English :

> Unable to process your order. please try again

[image: IMG: mobile error]

I have already tried clearing the cache for the Play Store app on my device, cleared the cache on my browser on my desktop computer, and I tried 2 different credit cards (one Visa, one Mastercard, both working on Amazon).

I am able to download free apps, and was able to purchase apps from the Play Store in the past.
My phone runs Android 5.1.1 and is not rooted.

Does anyone know what the problem could be or even where I could find more helpful error messages?

Comment: Sure. Imgur provides an easy resize functionality. Append the URL and the image is resized. See here to know what to append: [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I was trying to purchase the app with the same Google account as the one I use for publishing apps, which is clearly forbidden by [Google's policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/141659?hl=en) :

> Please note that it is against Google’s policies to purchase your own
>   application. You will receive an error message when you try to
>   purchase your own application.

Pitty that the error message wasn't a bit more helpful, but the mistake was mine anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a universal answer. Getting exactly the same error when trying to rent a movie, and I have never published any apps.